# Mongoose populate a field without ObjectId?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, populate

I have a schema:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var TicketSchema = new Schema({
externalId: String,
name: String,
items: [{
    externalId: String,
    price: Number,
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1
    },
    comment: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    entity: {
        type: String,
        ref: 'Entity'
    }
}],
tableId: String
});

mongoose.model('Ticket', TicketSchema);
```

And I want to populate entity field with an unique field other than ObjectId.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: This Package might be helpful https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment, It will use Number type in `_id` starting from 0,1 ++ instead of `ObjectId`

Comment: @p0k8_  This is not I meant. I already have an unique field. But it's not _id. So, how can I populate mongoose model with using this field?

Comment: You can achieve that the same way as you would with ObjectId. According to mongoose valids refs can be `ObjectId, Number, String, and Buffer`. Its just that the collection you're referring should have that referred value as its `_id` field.

Answer (score 3):

Though late answer. Please check Populate Virtuals for Mongoose 4.5.0

Click the link below

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

And scroll down or search for Populate Virtuals you will see it does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I found Views as one useful approach, though not sure it is the most efficient! For example, in movielens database, I wanted to refer 'movieId' in ratings collection to 'movieId' in the movies collection using 'movieId' as foreign key.

```
db.createView('rating-movie-view','ratings',[{$lookup:{from:"movies",localField:"movieId",foreignField:"movieId",as:"ratings_movie"}},{ $project:{'userId':1,'movieId':1,'rating':1,'timestamp':1,'ratings_movie.title':1,'ratings_movie.genres':1 } }])
```

New view "rating-movie-view"  thus created has the required fields 'title and 'genres'.

```
db["rating-movie-view"].findOne()

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("598747c28198f78eef1de7a3"),
    "userId" : 1,
    "movieId" : 1129,
    "rating" : 2,
    "timestamp" : 1260759185,
    "ratings_movie" : [
        {
            "title" : "Escape from New York (1981)",
            "genres" : "Action|Adventure|Sci-Fi|Thriller"
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope this useful!

Those who are not familiar with movielens data here are the schema

```
var MovieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  movieId: Number,
  title: String,
  genres: String,
});

var RatingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userid: Number,
  movieId:Number,
  rating: Number,
  timestamp:Number,
});
```

//View schema

```
var RatingViewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userid: Number,
  movieId:Number,
  rating: Number,
  timestamp:Number,
  rating_movie:{title:String,genres:String}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

const blogs = this.blogModel
.find(find)
.populate('blogCategory', 'name -_id');

Note -_id will exclude the object _id

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly.

In Mongoose model, in case we do not specify a primary key, it automatically adds in an extra field called *ObjectId* and assigns a unique value for each object.

In case we need to specify our own key, we can do it by specifying the *key* property.

For example:

```
mongoose.model('Todo', {
  todoID: {
    type: String,
    key: true
  },
  text: {
    type: 'text'
  },
  done: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
  },
  items: [{
    entity: {
      type: String,
      ref: 'Entity'
    }
  }]
});
```

I hope, this is what you meant.

If you are asking about fetching objects based on Items -> entity's property,

```
Todo.find({'items.entity.type':required_type}, function(err, foundTodos){
      // ---
   });
```

Thanks,

Comment: I don't want to use 'find' query. I just want to use populate 'entity' by a field that is not ObjectID but it's unique.

Answer (score -5):

Use [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto) to hash something unique like the objectId , and then save it to your entities.

```
Var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', ticket.objectId).digest('hex');
```

Ticket.entities= hash;